# update product thumbnail ,small image and base image programatically Magento

Tags: image, magento, zend-framework, set

> need to update the product thumbnail , small image and base image
>   programatically
>
> for this i a using a below code

```
$collection1->addImageToMediaGallery($importDir,$mediaArray,false);

    //$collection1->setStoreId(0);
        $collection1->save();
if (isset($mediaGallery['images'])){
            //loop through the images
            foreach ($mediaGallery['images'] as $image){
            //set the first image as the base image
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(array($collection1->getId()), array('image'=>$image['file'],'thumbnail'=>$image['file'],'small_image'=>$image['file']), 0);
            //stop
            break;
            }
            }
```

with this code a

> image adding to the gallery
>
> but i need to set the latest image to set as image and base image

.Please suggest how can i achieve this thanks

Answer (score 1):

check below url

http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-import-product-images-from-external-url-in-magento/

hope this help you

Comment: also check http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5715/how-to-programatically-import-product-and-set-images-to-default

Comment: The above link you gave doesn’t exist. Instead provide some explanation. A link may never exist in the future.